# how to convert a statistique result to percentage in python flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to convert the result that i am getting from the list , i do something which is nearest to be achieved but still have irregular result

this is what i do :

```
{% for item in listWebDetect %}
        <li>. <b>{{ item.description }}</b> </li>
        <li>. Précision : {{ '{0:0.0f}'.format(item.score *100)}} %</li>
{% endfor %}
```

this i what i get :

```
. Tom Cruise
. Précision : 1088 %
```

that's what I want without exceeding 100% :

```
. Tom Cruise
. Précision : 100 %
```

Comment: `min(item.score * 100, 100)`?

Comment: So you want to get rid of the decimal part? If that is the case, use ```int(item.score *100)``` and change the ```{0:0.0f}``` to ```{0}```.

Comment: What's the desired output? `item.score` is equal to 10.88 what you want it to become?

Comment: i wnat somtihng like this  20%,100%,55% not 108%,200% so without going beyond 100%, the 100% should be the max score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item's score is greater than 1 and that's the reason you get 1088.
Have a look at the value without multiplying it with 100. 1088 divided by 100 is 10.88, is this maybe already the percentage you want to get by multiplying?

Comment: the result before i do that is 10.871999740600586 , 0.4115999937057495,0.3880000114440918

Comment: i think they are already a percentage , but it look very long , is there any option to minimize it

Comment: Yes for sure, try the function &amp;quot;round&amp;quot; it&amp;#39;s a built-in function. You can use it at follows: "round(10.78638493, 2)" the second argument is the counter of numbers after the comma, so in the case above the result would be: "10.79".
   
And don't forget to mark my answer as solution :)